# Understanding Joomla Structure

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to Joomla and can't help but notice the difficulty in understanding page structure.

Right now the website has a page for example: domain.com/index.php/aboutustab

So it seems index.php is required to render all pages and the "aboutustab" seems to be an article but i can't find where the content in the aboutustab is being pulled from and how?

I looked into Article manager but the content is not there.

By content i mean all the text that is suppose to show up and etc.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading everything in the beginners section of the Joomla docs [located here](http://docs.joomla.org/Beginners).

What you're seeing is a menu option, not an article. Read the docs, they really do help.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 1.6/7/2.5 the index.php is shown if you haven't enabled Joomla! "**Search Engine Friendly URLs**" option in the **SEO Settings** panel in the Site tab of the Global Preferences.

In conjunction with using the "**Use URL rewriting**" (which requires you to enable either the Joomla! **.htaccess** file on Apache servers or the **web.config** file on IIS7 servers) these settings remove the index.php from the browsers location bar. Joomla! still passes everything through the index.php but it's not visible to the end user.

The content you're seeing would typically be in an Article but it may not have the same title as that displayed on the website - the title can be over-ridden in several places.  The other possibility is that it's in a Custom HTML module, which is essentially a mini article that you can place in module positions.

As for page structures, they are controlled by the active template (a template is a set of php, css, js and image files in a directory, usually of the same name as the template). A template typically provide a core content location (called the component area) and a variety of module positions. Most Joomla! templates support a variety of standard module positions including top, header, footer, copyright, user1...user5 etc.

The page is assembled by pulling together all of these elements (articles, modules, etc) and inserting them into the template.

HTH

Craig